# the application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android

I have built a game. When the user clicks a button on the main page, he is redirected to another activity for a predefined time(say 20 s) and then he returns to the main page where he can choose another button. Now, this works perfectly on the emulator but on the phone when I clicks another button on the main page, it says the application has stopped unexpectedly. Force close. However, if I wait for say 3 s before clicking another button, it works. Is it because the images on the background of the buttons are too heavy?? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the logcat facility to find the exact Exception that occurs in your code and then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

hey! i found out what was wrong. There was one picture which was too heavy!! it works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error results from the widget like `textview` and so on, please delete the line related to something like `textview`.